# How to linkup two arrays in Html angular5

Tags: angular

I have two arrays like one is **City** and another is **Zipcode**

```
cities=[{name:"aaa"},{name:"bbb"},{name:"ccc"},{name:"ddd"}]
  zipcode=[{num:"111"},{num:"222"},{num:"333"},{num:"444"}]
```

How to link up two arrays. If i use two forloops, then cities and zipcode becomes twice. Can anyone please help
I am expecting output like this
aaa-111
bbb-222
ccc-333
ddd-444

But i am not getting expected result.
I tried this.
[linkup array of data stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wj7dta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Why can't you just do it in the component? (typescript file)

Comment: This is a big design smell. Don't use parallel arrays. use a single arrays of objects, where each object has a city name and a zip code. I these arrays come from two different places, then use your TypeScript code to combine them into a single array of objects. A component is not just a view. It's also a TypeScript class, where you can write TypeScript code.

Comment: I tried in ts file also using mapping,but i am not getting

Comment: What have you tried then?

Comment: i agree with @JBNizet .. you should not have parallel arrays

Comment: Hi did my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html like this

```
<li *ngFor="let x of cities;let i=index">
     <div class="form-group" (click)="City(x)">
        <label>{{x.name}}-{{zipcode[i].num}}</label>
     </div>              
</li>
```

Use the index of the cities array to target the corresponding zipcode array's element. But for this to work you need to ensure that the 2 arrays are of same length and have same index refering to same values in both of the arrays

See updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmhwhy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**OR**

You can combine the 2 arrays in ngOnInit method using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like shown below.

```
ngOnInit () {        
    this.cities.map((x:any, i) => x.num = this.zipcode[i].num);
  }
```

Then use in html like

```
<div class="form-group" (click)="City(x)">
  <label>{{x.name}}-{{x.num}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the index, why not simply use `zipcode[i].num`

Something like this:

```
<div class="admin-page">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="co col-md-12">
          <li *ngFor="let x of cities;let i=index">
            <div class="form-group" (click)="City(x)">
              <label>{{x.name}}-{{zipcode[i].num}}</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> Here's an Updated [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-in-two-arrays?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.